# Calculating VWAP in Pandas per day

Tags: pandas, technical-indicator

Based on this answer:
[Pandas Efficient VWAP Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298789/pandas-efficient-vwap-calculation)

I see how one can efficiently make a vwap on a period of candles.

`df['vwap_pandas'] = (df.v*(df.h+df.l)/2).cumsum() / df.v.cumsum()`

However, what if I had a dataset with hundreds of days with one-minute candles and I want to calculate the VWAP on a per-day basis. I have a column which is the day, e.g. "2000-01-01". How could I do a group by day, and apply the above vwap function?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem, trying to calculate the  vwap per group: Minute.